# Problema al instalar CyberPanel

Tags: python, cpanel, msql

Al instalar Cyberpanel se me frena aquí, no se que hacer y soy un novato, mi sistema es ubuntu 22.04 y mi servidor esta en ovh, no se que mas hacer porque he buscado entodas partes y nada:

````
  Downloading decorator-3.4.0.tar.gz (30 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in decorator setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.```
````

Comment: Parece ser un problema de versión de setuptools. Mira esta página donde proponen una solución. https://debugah.com/python-pip-error_-2to3-is-invalid-problem-solving-20863/

Comment: @CandidMoe realmente lo hice y nada :(

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es un problema de versión de utilitarios

Answer (score 0):

Si no encontraste nada en internet:

- Ya consultaste en la documentacion de CyberPanel?
- En el Discord oficial?

Si no encuentras ahí solución o ayuda, probablemente hayas encontrado un bug. En los sitios oficiales, seguramente encuentres más respuestas